# Is there feature in Pyramid to specify a route in the template like Django templates?

Tags: python, pyramid

For example in Django if I have a url named 'home' then I can put {% url home %} in the template and it will navigate to that url. I couldn't find anything specific in the Pyramid docs so I am looking to tou Stack Overflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The brackets depend on the templating engine you are using, but `request.route_url('home')` is the Python code you need inside.

For example, in your desired template file:

- jinja2--> `{{ request.route_url('home') }}`
- mako/chameleon--> `${ request.route_url('home') }`

If your route definition includes pattern matching, such as `config.add_route('sometestpage', '/test/{pagename}')`, then you would do `request.route_url('sometestpage', pagename='myfavoritepage')`

Comment: Your answer was correct and I will accept and vote you up but I haven't been back because I found out how to do it on my own but my reputation is too low that I couldn't answer my own question or I would have.

Comment: Which solution did you prefer instead?

Comment: Well I was using mako templates and found the same solution in the docs but thanks anyways!